# How does an ISV become a supported "patch vendor"?

Tags: vsphere

The vSphere 4.0 VUM [release notes](http://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere4/doc/vsp_vum_40_rel_notes.html) has a list of supported OSes and applications in the 'Interoperability and Supported Operating Systems' section. How does an ISV with a custom linux-based VA get on that list ? Is there a process for adding support for a new OS + app ? I couldn't find anything from the online docs but perhaps my search skills are lacking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that those are OSes/Apps that were prioritized by VMWare for testing and support.  When they mark something as supported, they are basically promising that it will work on the system, meaning if something in the virtualization messes it up, VMWare is on the hook to help out.

It seems unlikely that just any ISV can get on the list, but the only way to be sure would be to contact VMWare about your interest in becoming fully tested/supported.